# I cant install team fortress 2 via steam?

Tags: steam

I followed the tutorial from [omgubuntu.co.uk](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2012/11/reddit-users-bypass-valve-linux-beta-invitations)

After running `steam steam://open/games` in the gnome-terminal I tried to install
*Team Fortress 2*; the link is `steam://run/440`

I also opened the link in my web-browser and selected Steam to start it up but nothing happens.

How to install Team Fortress 2 via Steam?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't at the moment when you aren't in beta.

> 'TF2 is screwy because you need to be really in the beta (i.e. have
>   one of the two beta subscriptions on your account) for it to work.'

From [Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux_gaming/comments/12qs6z/steam_for_linux_its_here_deb_in_the_link/c6xp9t0).